# Is passing a pointer by reference valid for getadrinfo in C++

Tags: c++, linux

I need to create a C++ socket class with a function that calls getaddrinfo() (which takes 'struct addrinfo **res' as the 4th argument).

In order to get this to work I used a pointer by reference to pass the 'singleAddress' variable.  I read that this is bad practice but I'm not sure how to make this code work otherwise.

The code below works perfectly. My question I guess is if using a *& is good practice or if there is a better way of rewriting this call and still having a fucntion that returns a usable addrinfo structure?

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class getAddress
{
public:
     int getAddressInfo(char* host, char* port, struct addrinfo *&singleAddress);
};

int getAddress::getAddressInfo(char* host, char* port, struct addrinfo *&singleAddress)
{
    int ret;
    struct addrinfo addCriteria;

    memset(&addCriteria, 0, sizeof(addCriteria));
    addCriteria.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    addCriteria.ai_socktype =  SOCK_STREAM;
    addCriteria.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    ret = getaddrinfo(host, port, &addCriteria, &singleAddress);
    if (ret != 0)
        return -1;

    cout << "> " << singleAddress->ai_family << endl;
    cout << "> " << singleAddress->ai_socktype << endl;   //<-- These must match

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int res;
    struct addrinfo *inVal;

    if (argc < 3)
        cout << "Usage: main [domain] [port]" << endl;

    getAddress adObj;
    res = adObj.getAddressInfo(argv[1], argv[2], inVal);
    if (res == 0)
    {
        cout << "-> " << inVal->ai_family << endl;
        cout << "-> " << inVal->ai_socktype << endl;  //<-- These must match
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: It is fine to pass a pointer by reference, if you are using APIs that require pointers. What I fail to see is the point of your `getAddress` class.

Comment: You should call freeaddrinfo to free the struct you get from getaddrinfo

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I wrote the class as a an example only for the purpose of this question. It's not really meant for anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fine to pass a pointer by reference, if you are using APIs that require pointers. What I fail to see is the point of your `getAddress` class. –  juanchopanza